# Probability that server served all the orders incorrectly

Tags: probability

Suppose, we have 4 people A, B,C,D go to an ice-cream shop  and each person order a single sundae. The server took down the order but forgot to mark for whom each sundae was for, and hence served a random sundae to each of the four persons. What is the probability that none of the friends got the sundae that they ordered?(Assume: *each order a distinctive sundae*).

**My solution** :
total ways in which we can arrange the dish = 4! = 24
then, I brute force favorable outcomes:

At first I shifted B in A place , D in C place --> BADC, similarly BCDA and BDAC (3 cases).

I did this process repeatedly two more times via moving C in A place, D in A place.

So, in total (3+3+3) = 9 favorable cases. Hence the answer was $\frac{9}{24}$ or $\frac{3}{8}$.

Is there a more intuitive way to approach this problem ?

Comment: You can use derangement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: @MathLover Wow!! first time even hearing it but this is what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: Interesting how you can’t just multiply the probabilities that each gets the wrong order: ($\frac{3}{4}$)*($\frac{2}{3})*...$ because there’s a chance that the correct order for (say $B$) was ordered by $A$, meaning there’s not a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance that $B$ gets the wrong order at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is classic example of derangement principle.
It is given by $$n! \sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{i}}{i!}$$
You can also derive this formula from inclusion - exclusion principle if you didn't know it before.